# Programmatically merge cells in Openoffice

Tags: perl, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I want to programm a script, which should generate a OpenOffice-Calc table.
I have downloades the package "libooolib-perl" for Debian, and it works good, but I have a problem: 
I can't concentrate Cells. I want the headline look like that:

```
This is the Head-Line of the Document                                 |
This is subheadline 1 | This is subheadline 2 | This is subheadline 3 |
This is content 1     | This is content 2     | This is content 3     |
This is content 4     | This is content 5     | This is content 6     |
```

As you see the first Line contains 3 cells. As far as I know, I am not able to archive this by using csv or another non-binary format, so I need a proper Library, which can concentrate cells.

Comment: to center (a special form of text aligment and/or justification); I think you mean `merge cells` here (a.o.p. `split cells`)

Answer (score 1):

`cellSpan` does the job!

```
use OpenOffice::OODoc;
my $document = odfDocument(file=>'filename.odt',create=> 'text');
my $table=$document->appendTable("Table", 4, 3);
$document->cellSpan($table,"A1",3);
$document->cellValue($table, "A1", "This is the Head-Line of the Document");
#(...)
$document->save;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the linked perl module does not support merging cells.

Perhaps the documentation of OpenOffice document format helps:

http://books.evc-cit.info/oobook/book_onepart.html#merged-spreadsheet-cells-section

It contains code samples, albeit in python, perhaps you can use the knowledge to implement the missing function in libooolib-perl